# Setting up storage servers with data replication and failover fallback

Tags: 14.04, server, filesystem, file-sharing, storage

Environment:
2 x Web Servers
2 x Storage Servers

How can I setup my web servers to have access put data into Storage Server #1, and have a failover so that if Storage Server #1 is down, it should put/get files to/from Storage Server #2 instead?

Also with this, what are the best options for replication of data between the two Storage Servers?
I have been looking into GlusterFS, is that recommended for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think for data replication you should use drbd . and for failover you can use heartbeat which are both opensource and freeware softwares . 
You can get more information by reading this. 
http://nathan-renault.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Installation_et_Configuration_drbd_heartbeat.pdf